# How can I send the id of a table object to a bootstrap3 modal in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Companies view in my Rails app, and the company has_many key_contacts, which are displayed in a table. Key_contacts has_many phone_numbers and email_addresses, also shown in the table. If the key_contact has not yet got a phone number or an email address associated with it, I show a bootstrap button that launches a modal to add a new phone number. All of this works fine.

My issue is that the bootstrap modal needs me to pass through the key_contact_id in order for the phone number to correctly associate with the key_contact. I can't seem to work out whether Rails will let me send the data through to the modal using the link_to API, or whether I have to use JQuery to take the id from the button (as I can set the id to the key_contact_id relatively easily per the below code).

Can anyone help me out here please?

Relevant code from the key_contacts_table:

```
<% @company.key_contacts.each do |con| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to con.full_name, con %></td>
              <% if con.phone_numbers.blank? %>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <td><%= link_to "Add Phone Number", '#', id: con.id, data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#phone_number_modal"}, class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %></td>
                </div>
              <% else %>...
```

Relevant code from the phone_number_modal:

```
  <%= form_for(@phone_number, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'phone_number'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @phone_number.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@phone_number.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this phone_number from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
   <% @phone_number.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
   </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :number, "Phone Number", :class => "control-label" %>
   </br>
    <%= f.text_field :number, :placeholder => "Enter phone number" %>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.hidden_field :key_contact_id %>
   </div>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn btn-success" %>
   </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In other modals I add objects that belong_to the company (which is being viewed), so it's relatively straightforward to pass the @company.id through to the modal being called. In this instance I can't do that as the key_contacts all belong_to the company, and there's no easy way to select the specific key_contact that I've clicked the button for as far as I know. Any help or guidance on the "rails way" of doing this would be gratefully received.

Comment: Tried the approach in this example?: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work similarly to the code I've implemented (below) so I'll just leave it alone as it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I've got this to work using (yet more) Javascript - the code is below. If anyone can give me a better answer I'd appreciate it.

```
    $('body').delegate('*[data-target="#phone_number_modal"]', 'click', function(){
     var Contactid;
     Contactid = (this.id);
   //pass the organization_id to the hidden text box
    $('#phone_number_key_contact_id').val(Contactid);
    });
});
```